# Highcharts not updating series stops

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to draw a chart (solid gauge), with an initial array of stops, I'm trying to update the stops (when some new data comes in), however highcharts isn't responding to this update and the colours of the series represent the initial array - not the newly give one.

I've recreated this in the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c12ttgh3/1/)

using this code

```
$('#container-speed').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
    stops: [[0.1, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
           [0.5, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
           [0.9, '#a2a2a2']] // grey
  });
```

Click the Change Stops button and you will notice the "Speed" chart does not change colour to "grey" - as defined in the new stops array.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution : [credit : @PawelFus(highcharts) for addressing similar problem]

```
var chartX=  $('#container-speed').highcharts();
$('#changeStops').click(function(){
chartX.yAxis[0].update({
    stops: [[0.1, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
           [0.5, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
           [0.9, '#a2a2a2']] // grey
  },false); 
    chartX.series[0].bindAxes();
    chartX.redraw(true);
});
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/c12ttgh3/3/)  and  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/c12ttgh3/4/)